# Display text if image is not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm coding a custom SharePoint Item_XX.html template which is feeding in data from my SharePoint custom list. I'm not sure how to 'break up' script though. How do I use an if-else statement where the output displays html?

You'll see I'm trying to say: 
If there is LogoSrc data, add the data to the image src. Otherwise display text (dtaa from the title field)

```
<script> if (!LogoSrc==null){ </script>
    <img src="_#= $htmlEncode(LogoSrc) =#_" />
<script> } else { </script>
    <p style="font-size: 13pt; font-family: 'Malgun Gothic', Arial, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-weight: 700;">_#= Title =#_</p>
<script> } </script>
```

Comment: What's the div element in which the else condition will go??

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Item_XX.html files requires a specific script syntax. The solution would be:

```
<!--#_ if(LogoSrc){ _#-->
    <img src="_#= $htmlEncode(LogoSrc) =#_" />
<!--#_ } _#--> 
<!--#_ if(LogoSrc.isEmpty){ _#-->
    <p style="font-size: 13pt; font-family: 'Malgun Gothic', Arial, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-weight: 700; text-transform: uppercase;">_#= Title =#_</p>
<!--#_ } _#-->
```